# how to catch loss of internet exception while running a automation test using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have a test suite which has 1000 test data, and it has to be tested using selenium automation.

Assuming that my 500 tests have already ran and i loss internet connectivity, here i want to handle the internet connectivity exception.

Can this be done using selenium, or we need a 3 party tool to handle this. Please suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: I briefly misread this as "loss of interest exception"

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about selenium web driver but, there is an exception that can be thrown when specific time has been elapsed, provided by Selenium which is `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException()` (assuming that losing connection is one reason for timeout) 
so we come up with a real use need of an asynchronous call provided by an interface called Future

```
A Future represents the result of an asynchronous computation
```

*as stated by Javadoc*

which has a method `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException`
so you can use it,
after changing a *sample usage code* provided by Oracle Javadoc I came up with something that can solve your problem

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

interface ArchiveSearcher {
    String search(String target) throws InterruptedException;
}

class ArchiveSearcherClass implements ArchiveSearcher {
    ArchiveSearcherClass() {

    }

    @Override
    public String search(String target) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.wait(2000); //in your case you can just put your work here 
            //this is just an example
            if (("this is a specific case that contains " + target)
                    .contains(target))
                return "found";
            return "not found";
        }
    }

}

class App {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ArchiveSearcher searcher = new ArchiveSearcherClass();

    void showSearch(final String target)
      throws InterruptedException {
    Future<String> future
      = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws InterruptedException {
            return searcher.search(target);
        }});
   System.out.println("remember you can do anythig asynchronously"); // do other things while searching
        try {
            System.out.println(future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); //try to run this then change it to 3 seconds
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("time out exception");
//          throw new org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException(); 
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

}}

public class Test extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App app1 = new App();
        try {
            app1.showSearch("query");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```